# hadoop eclipse plugin build/configure

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-plugins

I have been able to configure and start hdfs(apache hadoop) in linux environment. I tried various ways to setup eclipse environment for hadoop with HADOOP ECLIPSE PLUGIN. Only plugin jar that is recongnized by eclipse is at some 1280 jira issue, other methods wont even recognize, like building eclipse plugin from hadoop src and as such. and the patched jar from 1280 link says "cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:3515 EOFException". And many blogs/forums say different methods to patch hadoop, build with various tools etc.. etc..
Isn't there a stable hadoop project to configure with eclipse so developer's can quickly get the environment and work on various examples? I don't want to work with Cloudera VM because it makes me not to understand hadoop in a normal way, and installation is a process with big files. Please someone help me to get hadoop environment in a stable way.

Thanks 
Chakri

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Hadoop successfully? On my 0.20.2 Hadoop setup, the following steps worked to get a functioning Eclipse plugin (after I had installed Hadoop itself via the command line):

1. Set up Eclipse, copy plugin and restart; u[se the patched plugin](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1280) (add hadoop-eclipse-plugin-0.20.3-SNAPSHOT.jar to the local Eclipse/plugins folder).
2. Switch to the Map/Reduce perspective. If no Map/Reduce Locations tab appears, go to Window->Show View->Other to active it. Make sure to know the correct ports for hdfs (can be found in core-site.xml in the Hadoop setup) and mapreduce jobs (can be found in mapred-site.xml) are running.
3. The "DfS Locations" in the Eclipse plugin need manual refresh to see new data that was just added so if you right-click and upload a file to HDFS, make sure to refresh
4. To create a new Hadoop project in Eclipse, go to New Project -> Map/Reduce Project

Answer (score 0):

@Claudia other than this much setting while creating new hadoop location, is there anything else related to changing advanced parameters? In the general tab, the ports are correct but still I am getting exception - 
Error:Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
master node is the same node where eclipse is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ConnectException, if everything else has been done as instructed by Claudia, if you are still getting this exception in the DFS locations, that means the plugin you are using is not compatible with either the version of hadoop or the version of eclipse you are using (generally the latter).
In which case, please refer [here](http://linuxjunkiemonkey.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/eclipse-apache-hadoop-plugin-build-1-0-2/) in order to compile a new plugin for the eclipse version you are using.